# Entity Framework Data Migrations for Different Environments

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

There are some base data specific for Dev/Test/Prod environments.

We are using now Entity Framework Migrations for all the environments but do not know how to specify migrations for particular environments in a way that we specify a migration to be executed only on Dev/Test/Prod.

This could be accomplished in Fluent Migrator with Tag attributes. But what about Entity Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say 'base data' I assume you mean Seeding each environment. Migrations provide a [seeding mechanism](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) for this. Within the Seed() you can differentiate environments as you would in regular code. We like to use Web.config transform setting:

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
    if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeployEnvironment"] == "UAT")
    {
        context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Test User" },
        );
    }
    else if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DeployEnvironment"] == "PROD")
    {
        context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Production User" },
        );
    }
}
```

Another option is compiler directives:

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
#if DEBUG
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Test User" },
    );
#else
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Production User" },
    );
#endif
}
```

As far as applying the migrations themselves, we follow [this process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501) in development. When we are ready to deploy to UAT, we can just point the connection string at UAT and run migrations or we can [create a script](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2013/05/generate-sql-script-from-entity.html) to update the database. In PROD we do [this](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1).