# Complete guide on how to use Migrations with several Azure SQL databases, connectionstrings and Azure App Services publish profiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, azure-web-app-service

I have a MVC project hosted in Azure App Services with Azure SQL databases for the data. I have a development, staging/acceptance and production environment (App Service) and as for the databases i have development, staging/acceptance, production and a local DB (mdf). I have 3 publish profiles (1 for each environment).

I (think) to understand that i can use the CTOR of the DbContext class to set a connectionstring from the web.config based on the name:

Ex.

```
public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DbContextNameThatResidesInWebConfig") 
{           
     // ...               
}
```

If i am not using migrations i am able to do what i want without any issues. When using migrations (since i don't want any data loss when changing my model) i am getting several issues on model creation, i tried using several methods in my above CTOR:

```
// this is a custom Seeder that inherits DropDatabaseAlways/WhenModelChanges
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new ContractCareSeeder()); 

// from what i understand, this tells to use the latest migrations applied
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Migrations.Configuration>());
```

**Configuration.cs:**

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    // seeding method ...
}
```

But i always receive errors like, "there is already a table called XXX ..." even when i have succesfully executed the Update-Database command in the console it still fails.

I am quite lost in this and can't seem to find what is the best way of handling my scenario. I want to be able to use multiple publish profiles (later on we will use development slots but not now) and there there is also configuration possible. I can see all my connections from my web.config along with update database checkbox but i can't seem to find the right way of configuring everything together...

Can anyone assist me, suggest me or provide any help of any kind?
Kind regards!

Comment: Any process now?

Comment: @JoeyCai, no not yet, i have to continue develop certain features, once this is done i will try the migrations scenario again and see what my findings are, i will post back here. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET 5 introduces improved support for controlling application behavior **across multiple environments**, such as `development`, `staging`, and `production`. Environment variables are used to indicate which environment the application is running in, allowing the app to be configured appropriately.

You could set `ASPNET_ENV` with the current environment you want to use. If you need to check whether the application is running in a particular environment, use `env.IsEnvironment("environmentname")`

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseBrowserLink();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

For more details you could refer to this [article](https://dotnet.today/en/aspnet5-vnext/fundamentals/environments.html#startup-conventions) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480435/how-to-use-code-first-migrations-with-azure-app-service/50480660#50480660) which though is asp.net core.

Comment: Joey Cai, determing the environments or databases are not the issue, and i am not using Core so i can't set the Environment variables as far as i know. The issue i have is that i am confused about how to correctly use the Migrations along with seeders for multiple environments (App Services publish profiles) AND Azure databases. I don't want to loose data when changing my model. I can use it properly without Migrations and publish to the right database or App Service but when adding migrations i get issues about existing tables for example. (if i need to clear up some things let me know)

Comment: Without migrations, how do you switch your environment?

Comment: You could refer to this article [Entity Framework Data Migrations for Different Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41934490/entity-framework-data-migrations-for-different-environments).

Comment: Joey Cai, I switch environments by setting a contextName in my ApplicationDbContext CTOR (which determines my database), when publishing i have a publish profile for each environment. There is the issue in my opinion, in my publish profile(s) => Configure => Settings I can't make it work without receiving an error, i have tried different ways by checking/unchecking the "Update database" option or "Execute Code First Migrations". When i have migrations enabled i can publish but i can't write to my database configured in this configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the Link Joey Cai i will check that out today, looks a good way of using different environment but i don't think this will solve my issue with migrations. Will post an update. (Thank you)